# Integrating MQTT with PyQt4

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, mqtt

I'm looking to run a GUI built using PyQt which contains QLCDNumber that update automatically based upon subscription to my MQTT client running on a Pi. I am having trouble integrating the two sections of code I need. My GUI is below.

Basically when the topic wishing/speed updates I would like the LCD on the GUI to also update.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Think Physics: Technology Wishing Well")
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        mqttLCD = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self)
        mqttLCD.setNumDigits(1)
        client.connect('localhost', 1883)
        self.show()

    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, rc):
        print "Connected with result code: " + str(rc)
        client.subscribe("wishing/speed")

    def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
        print "Topic: ", msg.topic + '\nMessage: ' + msg.payload
        mqttLCD.display(msg.payload)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    global client = mqtt.Client()

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    Window.show()


    client.loop_start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

`client.loop_start()` returns immediately, but it is also very important for client operation. If you move it to after the `client.connect()` call then it should work.